# Apache NiFi- not able to get INFO logs in bulletin board

Tags: apache-nifi

I want to get the info of the processors in bulletin board in apache nifi..

I have changed the below line in logback.xml

'''<logger name="org.apache.nifi.processors" level="INFO" /'''

Also in processor settings i have set the bulletin level to INFO, though bulletin board not shows the info about the processor.It shows only the warning and error. help me to resolve this.

Also please suggest for below ,
Now by default all processors are set to WARN level bulletin..Is there any way to set the bulletin level as 'INFO' by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that as a processor basis
change processor's bulletin level to INFO like below.

I suppose you can not change default level for all processors. Anyway, bulletin board can only show a few number of logs, so it will quickly disappear and not useful. it is important to trace just crucial logs on bulletin board.

[image]

Comment: I have done this change also,but still I am not getting info logs in bulletin..Is there any property or settings to be changed?

Comment: your processor may not be producing info level  log.

Comment: Yes I am using Querydatabasetable processor it is not showing INFO logs..but the processors like LISTSFTP,SPLITTEXT,REPLACETEXT processors are showing INFO logs.

Comment: Now by default all processors are set to WARN level bulletin..Is there any way to set the bulletin level as 'INFO' by default